# Extra namespace in xsl output eclipse

Tags: eclipse, xslt

Since our company is moving from AX to SAP I'm also making a 'shift' from visual studio to eclipse. I'd thought it would be nice to start with a small xslt project but when trying my existing (made in VS) xsl I noticed some differences.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:msxsl="http://schemas.microsoft.com/dynamics/2008/01/documents/SalesInvoice">
  <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes" />

  <xsl:strip-space elements="*" />

  <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()" />
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="msxsl:SalesType">
    <xsl:choose>
      <xsl:when test="(../msxsl:SalesType) = 'ReturnItem'">
        <xsl:element name="MessageType" namespace="http://schemas.microsoft.com/dynamics/2008/01/documents/SalesInvoice">384</xsl:element>
      </xsl:when>
      <xsl:otherwise>
        <xsl:element name="MessageType" namespace="http://schemas.microsoft.com/dynamics/2008/01/documents/SalesInvoice">380</xsl:element>
      </xsl:otherwise>
    </xsl:choose>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Generates an output xml with msxsl prefix xmlns:msxsl="http://schemas.microsoft.com/dynamics/2008/01/documents/SalesInvoice">380:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Envelope
     xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/dynamics/2008/01/documents/Message">
       <Header>
             <MessageId>{0E415D3C-6D46-4E4E-B8CA-9729B11BA}</MessageId>
             <SourceEndpoint>BAB</SourceEndpoint>
             <DestinationEndpoint>INVOIC_WKMP</DestinationEndpoint>
       <Action>http://schemas.microsoft.com/dynamics/2008/01/services/SalesSalesInvoiceService/read
             </Action>
       </Header>
       <Body>
             <MessageParts>
                    <SalesInvoice xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/dynamics/2008/01/documents/SalesInvoice">
                          <CustInvoiceJour class="entity">
                                 <AccountcategoryId>FFF</AccountcategoryId>
                                 <msxsl:MessageType
                                 xmlns:msxsl="http://schemas.microsoft.com/dynamics/2008/01/documents/SalesInvoice">380</msxsl:MessageType>
                          </CustInvoiceJour>
                    </SalesInvoice>
             </MessageParts>
       </Body>
</Envelope>
```

Whereas visual studio xsl leaves out the xmlns:msxsl specification (which is correct):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Envelope xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/dynamics/2008/01/documents/Message">
  <Header>
    <MessageId>{0E415D3C-6D46-4E4E-B8CA-9729B11BA}</MessageId>
    <SourceEndpoint>BAB</SourceEndpoint>
    <DestinationEndpoint>INVOIC_WKMP</DestinationEndpoint>
    <Action>http://schemas.microsoft.com/dynamics/2008/01/services/SalesSalesInvoiceService/read</Action>
  </Header>
  <Body>
    <MessageParts>
      <SalesInvoice xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/dynamics/2008/01/documents/SalesInvoice">
        <CustInvoiceJour class="entity">
          <AccountcategoryId>FFF</AccountcategoryId>
          <MessageType>380</MessageType>
        </CustInvoiceJour>
      </SalesInvoice>
    </MessageParts>
  </Body>
</Envelope>
```

Since it’s already in the http://schemas.microsoft.com/dynamics/2008/01/documents/SalesInvoice namespace 
I don’t want this addition here. Is there anything I can do to change this in eclipse?

Kind regards,

Mike

Comment: I don't know which XSLT processor Eclipse uses and in general I think at least with XSLT 1 there is no guarantee about used prefixes for namespaces, however, you could try whether using `<xsl:stylesheet exclude-result-prefixes="msxsl" ...>` improves the result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, Visual Studio is NOT correct to omit this namespace. If you don't want it included you should explicitly omit it using `xsl:exclude-result-prefixes="msxsl"`.

Comment: Thank you Michael!